# Longer than expected upload times for big query insert

Tags: google-bigquery

I am uploading data to big query as csv format with JSON schemas.  What I am seeing is the very long times to load into big query. I take the start and ending load times from the pollJob.getStatistics() when the load is DONE and compute a delta time as (startTime - endTime)/1000.  Then I look at the number of bytes loaded.  The data is from files stored in google cloud storage that I reprocess in app engine to do some reformatting.  I convert the string into a byte stream and then load as the contents of the load as follows:

```
public static void uploadFileToBigQuerry(TableSchema tableSchema,String tableData,String datasetId,String tableId,boolean formatIsJson,int waitSeconds,String[] fileIdElements)  {

    /* Init diagnostic */
    String projectId = getProjectId();

    if (ReadAndroidRawFile.testMode)  {
        String s = String.format("My project ID at start of upload to BQ:%s datasetID:%s tableID:%s json:%b \nschema:%s tableData:\n%s\n",
            projectId,datasetId,tableId,formatIsJson,tableSchema.toString(),tableData);
        log.info(s);
    }
    else  {
        String s = String.format("Upload to BQ tableID:%s tableFirst60Char:%s\n",
                tableId,tableData.substring(0,60));
        log.info(s);
    }

    /* Setup the data each time */
    Dataset dataset = new Dataset();
    DatasetReference datasetRef = new DatasetReference();
    datasetRef.setProjectId(projectId);
    datasetRef.setDatasetId(datasetId);
    dataset.setDatasetReference(datasetRef);

    try {
        bigquery.datasets().insert(projectId, dataset).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        if (ReadAndroidRawFile.testMode) {
            String se = String.format("Exception creating datasetId:%s",e);
            log.info(se);
        }
    }


    /* Set destination table */
    TableReference destinationTable = new TableReference();
    destinationTable.setProjectId(projectId);
    destinationTable.setDatasetId(datasetId);
    destinationTable.setTableId(tableId);

    /* Common setup line */
    JobConfigurationLoad jobLoad = new JobConfigurationLoad();

    /* Handle input format */
    if (formatIsJson)  {
        jobLoad.setSchema(tableSchema);
        jobLoad.setSourceFormat("NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON"); 
        jobLoad.setDestinationTable(destinationTable);
        jobLoad.setCreateDisposition("CREATE_IF_NEEDED");
        jobLoad.setWriteDisposition("WRITE_APPEND");
        jobLoad.set("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
    }
    else  {
        jobLoad.setSchema(tableSchema); 
        jobLoad.setSourceFormat("CSV"); 
        jobLoad.setDestinationTable(destinationTable);
        jobLoad.setCreateDisposition("CREATE_IF_NEEDED");
        jobLoad.setWriteDisposition("WRITE_APPEND");
        jobLoad.set("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
    }

    /* Setup the job config */
    JobConfiguration jobConfig = new JobConfiguration();
    jobConfig.setLoad(jobLoad);
    JobReference jobRef = new JobReference();
    jobRef.setProjectId(projectId);

    Job outputJob = new Job();
    outputJob.setConfiguration(jobConfig);
    outputJob.setJobReference(jobRef);

    /* Convert input string into byte stream */
    ByteArrayContent contents = new ByteArrayContent("application/octet-stream",tableData.getBytes());  

    int timesToSleep = 0;
    try {
        Job job = bigquery.jobs().insert(projectId,outputJob,contents).execute();
        if (job == null)  {
            log.info("Job is null...");
            throw new Exception("Job is null");
        }

        String jobIdNew = job.getId();
        //log.info("Job is NOT null...id:");
        //s = String.format("job ID:%s jobRefId:%s",jobIdNew,job.getJobReference());
        //log.info(s);

        while (true) {
            try{
                Job pollJob = bigquery.jobs().get(jobRef.getProjectId(), job.getJobReference().getJobId()).execute();
                String status = pollJob.getStatus().getState();
                String errors = "";
                String workingDataString = "";

                if ((timesToSleep % 10) == 0)  {
                    String statusString = String.format("Job status (%dsec) JobId:%s status:%s\n", timesToSleep, job.getJobReference().getJobId(), status);
                    log.info(statusString);
                }

                if (pollJob.getStatus().getState().equals("DONE")) {
                    status = String.format("Job done, processed %s bytes\n", pollJob.getStatistics().toString()); //  getTotalBytesProcessed());
                    log.info(status);  // compute load stats with this string
                    if ((pollJob.getStatus().getErrors() != null)) {
                        errors = pollJob.getStatus().getErrors().  toString();
                        log.info(errors);
                    }
```

The performance I get is as follows: the median upload of BYTES/(deltaTime) is 17 BYTES/sec!  Yes, bytes, not kilo or mega...

Worse is that sometimes for only a few hundred bytes, just one row, it takes up to 5 minutes.  I generally have no errors, but I am thinking that with this performance, I will not be able to upload each app before more data arrives.  I am processing with a task queue in a backends instance.  This task queue gets a time-out after about an hour of processing.

Is this poor performance because of the contents method?

Comment: I can second on this, I've seen poor performance today too.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

- If you are loading a small amount of data, you may be better off using TableData.insertAll() rather than a load job, which lets you post the data and have it be available immediately.
- Load jobs are Batch oriented jobs. That is, you can insert (more or less) as many as you'd like and they'll be processed when there are resources to do so. Sometimes you create a job and the worker pool is resizing so you have to wait. Sometimes the worker pool is full.
- If you provide a project & Job ID we can look into the performance of individual jobs to see  what's taking so long.
- Load jobs process in parallel; that is, once they start executing they should go very quickly, but the time to start executing may take a long time.
- There are three time fields in the job statistics. createTime, startTime, and endTime.

  - createTime is the moment the BigQuery server receives your request.
  - startTime is when BigQuery actually starts working on your job
  - endTime is when the job is completely done

  I'd expect that most of the time is being spent between create and start. If that is not the case for small jobs, then it means that something is strange is going on, and a Job ID would help diagnose the issue.

Comment: HI Jordan,  Really appreciate your prompt feedback and useful suggestions.  I will try the insertAll, AKA streaming.  I did check the timing as you suggested, often the pending is much longer and the running is short, but I attached some cases where running time was long for what I consider a short piece of data.

Comment: PROJECT ID is: mindful-highway-451

URL: https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/mindful-highway-451/jobs/

Comment: Example 1) Typical 80sec pending, 20 process...Job done, processed {"creationTime":"1395768754531","endTime":"1395768877498","load":{"inputFileBytes":"289","inputFiles":"1","outputBytes":"291","outputRows":"1"},"startTime":"1395768859444"}

Comment: EXAMPLE 2) pending 20, running almost 5 mintues for 2kByte of data...JobId:job_SydFpxwz683ATrKt4HdoBUoj_Z0   {"creationTime":"1395769250262","endTime":"1395769562176","load":{"inputFileBytes":"3410","inputFiles":"1","outputBytes":"1860","outputRows":"62"},"startTime":"1395769270675"}

Comment: EXAMPLE 3) SOCKET TIMEOUT..running almost 5 minute then failed JobId:job_DG8scC4cBGENkhH9hkAytgnh3zw     Exception inside while loop e:java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Timeout while fetching URL: https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/mindful-highway-451/jobs/job_DG8scC4cBGENkhH9hkAytgnh3zw

Comment: EXAMPLE 4) Pending 20 running almost 250...JobId:job_tVYay7mChNZpG_9DWEwnWdOd_60   {"creationTime":"1395772464968","endTime":"1395772732719","load":{"inputFileBytes":"282","inputFiles":"1","outputBytes":"286","outputRows":"1"},"startTime":"1395772489854"}

Comment: Hope the above example are readable...Thanks so much for having a look.  Hope I gave the correct information.

Comment: I looked at your example 2 (job_SydFpxwz683ATrKt4HdoBUoj_Z0 ). We waited around for 5 minutes for a worker between two stages of our import pipeline. I think we have our pool minimum size set too low (so we'll shrink back down when possible) which makes it hard to scale up when needed. I'll investigate; that said, this kind of thing can happen with Load jobs.

Comment: Makes sense and thanks.  I will consider moving to streaming, but it seems I have to convert my csv data into JSON to use the TableData content. I am looking for an example that allows me to keep my content as the byte stream.  Any ideas please?

Comment: Jordon, you menion load jobs can be in parallel.  Is there a recommended way to do this?  If a task queue is loaded with many uploads, can they be parallelized?  My understanding is that the queue is serial. I can only imagine firing off many loads, and then wait for status in parallel?  I am looking for ideas on how to improve performance is currently most of my backends time is spent waiting.  Any suggestions are appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: I have restructed code to do the batch processing suggested by Jordan.  Instead of waiting to check the status, I save the jobId string and other supporting data to dataStore.  Then another servlet scans through these jobIds to check the job status.  Thanks Jordan.  I want to pursue the insertAll, but would have to re-format the CSV data into JSON.  Does any know a way to use CSV content with insertAll.  I do have the schema available as it is used in the job-based insert.  I havent found a clean way to convert the CSV to the TableDataInsertAllRequest format.  Maybe this can another topic.